# I am looking for a way to use Vue props in a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am looking a way to use props in a function. Yet the console says `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`
How should I use props or pass the data to my function?

```html
<template>
</template>

<script>
  import {db} from '../plugins/firebase';

  export default {
    name: "VueComponent",
    props: {
      for : String
    },
    data: () => ({
      thanks: [],
    }),
    firestore() {
      return {
        comments: db.collection('thanks').doc(this.props.for).orderBy('lookingAtMyPost');
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

The error:

```
chat.js?id=217075c507b419bb0145:48071 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
    at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vuetify-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access props like you can data properties, you don't have to do `this.props.for` you can just do `this.for` and it will work in the same way.

However, It's worth noting, you can't modify props directly in a child component, you'd have to emit an event for that.

From the Vue docs:

> All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, but not the other way around. This prevents child components from accidentally mutating the parent’s state, which can make your app’s data flow harder to understand.

> In addition, every time the parent component is updated, all props in the child component will be refreshed with the latest value. This means you should not attempt to mutate a prop inside a child component. If you do, Vue will warn you in the console.

Read this article for more info on how to mutate props: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-emit-data-in-vue-beyond-the-vuejs-documentation

Comment: Thanks. That really helped!